# Start wrapping text in HTML table only after reaching max-width of TD

Tags: css, html-table

In HTML tables that are wider than the viewport, text is wrapped, so the table may fit after all. To force all fields on a single line (and possibly extend outside the viewing area) I use 'white-space: nowrap' for all TDs in the table.
This is just fine for most of my tables, but in one scenario this does not work very well. I have a table with 20 columns or so with terse column headings and content, except one, which is a description field of 256 characters maximum. Using 'nowrap' is quite right for all columns, but the description column is now a very wide column indeed.

Is there a (CSS) way to specify that fields should be as small as possible (no min-width), keep on one line (nowrap), except when longer than some maximum field width (max-with: 250px). It would be nice if it could be applied to all TDs, where a reduction of the maximum width would start other fields wrapping as well.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any success with that yet?